# No type or protocol error while protocol is imported

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

At first, in LoadingVC.h I declare a protocol:

```
@protocol VideoWorker <NSObject>

@required

@property (nonatomic) float progress;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL done;

-(void)beginWorking;

@end

@interface LoadingVC : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>
...
@end
```

then in BlurWorkerGPU.h

```
...
#import "LoadingVC.h"

@interface BlurWorkerGPU  : NSObject <VideoWorker> {
...
}
- (void)beginWorking;
@property(nonatomic)float progress;
@property(nonatomic)BOOL done;
 ...
@end
```

However, llvm says that

> "No type or protocol named 'VideoWorker'"

which is strange since I am importing the header where the protocol is defined. Any clues?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should forward declare protocol in .h files before you use it. Put this in the top of `BlurWorkerGPU.h`

```
@protocol VideoWorker;
```

Comment: That saved my night.

Answer (score 1):

check whether you are importing "BlurWorkerGPU.h" in "LoadingVC.h"

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions are

- import protocol

> @import 
>   **YOURPROTOCOLNAME**

- import Class in which protocol is declared

> `#import "YOURCLASSWHICHDECLAREDPROTOCOL.h"`

- Use @Class to import the class

> @class    YOURCLASSWHICHDECLAREDPROTOCOL;