# no type or protocol named 'NFCVASReaderSessionDelegate' while building Xamarin.iOS

Tags: exception, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, nfc

I am struggling to build my Xamarin.IOS a project since the last two days but I am unable to build it. I am continuously getting the following error:

no type or protocol named 'NFCVASReaderSessionDelegate' ProjectName.iOS C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets

Can someone tell me what could be the reason and why I am not getting rid of that error?

Comment: You should forward declare protocol in .h files before you use it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35658270/no-type-or-protocol-error-while-protocol-is-imported

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I am using Xamarin.iOS, so there are .cs files but no .h files.